# = expected after <context:component-scan

Tags: spring

I am writing the following in my Spring XML configuration

`<context: component-scan base-package="com.tea.one.beans"/>`

But I get an error saying `'= expected'` after component-scan.  I read the docs and several sites and can't figure out what the = should be for after component-scan.

Any idea what it should be? Thanks!

Comment: Extra space, it should be `<context:component-scan base-package="com.tea.one.beans"/>`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz you're right! Didn't know XML was space-sensitive...

Comment: @LuisMuñoz would you like to answer so I can accept it?